# Updating SOLR documents with big XML data file

Tags: .net, xml, solr, solrnet, solr4

I have created XML data file with the [Solr accepts POSTed XML messages](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages) format including 100,000 documents. The file size is 310MB and I tried to Post the file with ASP.NET application. When I try a smaller file, update commits successfully. But, with big XML file I get out-of-memory exception (which is acceptable, because I should load the file content to string variable and Post the string to the SOLR server). SolrNet does not provide any other method for Post, therefore, I can't use SolrNet client.

Is there any solution to post a big data file to the SOLR server instead of sending single document?
Can I do that on SOLR administration panel.

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/2c1e0923e148d37b211cce058108a4bc8b8fd6b5/SolrNet/ISolrConnection.cs#L41

Comment: You might be able to just post the XML file to solr. for example  curl http://localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<add><doc><field name="id">12345</field><field name="username">alphadevx</field><field name="firstname">John</field><field name="lastname">Collins</field><field name="classname">User</field></doc></add>'   from [http://www.alphadevx.com/a/374-Running-Solr-queries-and-updates-via-curl](http://www.alphadevx.com/a/374-Running-Solr-queries-and-updates-via-curl)

Comment: Why would you do that? At that size, you will hit all sorts of HTTP limitations in both Solr and Servlet containers.

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch I have a dump data file and I want to update Solr with .NET application.

Comment: Split it into multiple transactions. Use DataImportHandler. Maybe some other tricks. The file is just too large.